# Jsoup selector to fetch div id text

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jsoup

I have a html like this:

```
<div class="A">
 <div class="B">
    <span class="C" id="important">
        <strong>1234</strong>
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to fetch the value inside strong i.e **"1234".**

Using Jquery I would use ,

> $("#important").text()

But how do I do that in JSoup,

I tried

> doc.select("#important").first().text()

But it returned null exception saying that such element is not found. What am I doing wrong here?

Upadte:
[Jsoup Simulator](http://try.jsoup.org/) helped me solve the issue.

Comment: According to the [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)  what you're doing is right. Are you sure that `doc` isn't null ?

Comment: what is `doc` here? Are you sure that `doc` isn't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc.select("#important").children().first().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"A\">\r\n" + 
            " <div class=\"B\">\r\n" + 
            "    <span class=\"C\" id=\"important\">\r\n" + 
            "        <strong>1234</strong>\r\n" + 
            "    </span>\r\n" + 
            " </div>\r\n" + 
            "</div>");
    System.out.println(doc.select("#important").first().text()); 
}
```

Above code returns 1234.

It's obvious that something else is null. Divide your code like this:

```
    System.out.println(doc);
    Elements select = doc.select("#important");
    System.out.println(select);
    Element first = select.first();
    System.out.println(first);
    String text = first.text();
    System.out.println(text);
```

And you'll find what is the case.

Comment: Or, you know, use the debugger for what it's meant for instead of logging out every last thing.